# Linux multipath 1 lun not using all paths other luns OK

Tags: linux, rhel5, multipath

A new 50gb lun was added to the rhel5.8 linux server and we did a scan to 
detect and add. However multipath -ll shows that the 50gb lun is using only 1 path
while the old existing luns are on 2 paths.

```
#echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/host0/scan

# multipath -ll
mpath2 (3600a0b80002fbe78000010df55bad187) dm-8 IBM,1726-4xx  FAStT
size=50G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 rdac' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=6 status=enabled
  `- 1:0:0:3 sdh 8:112 active ready running
mpath1 (3600a0b80002fbe780000107d53df601c) dm-3 IBM,1726-4xx  FAStT
size=100G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 rdac' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=6 status=enabled
| `- 1:0:0:0 sdb 8:16  active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 2:0:0:0 sdc 8:32  active ghost running
awauatapps (3600a0b80002fbe0000000f8b5472ee8f) dm-6 IBM,1726-4xx  FAStT
size=100G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 rdac' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=6 status=active
| `- 2:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 1:0:0:2 sdf 8:80  active ghost running
gpsapps (3600a0b80002fbe78000010c9545afa11) dm-4 IBM,1726-4xx  FAStT
size=100G features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='1 rdac' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=6 status=active
| `- 1:0:0:1 sdd 8:48  active ready running
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=enabled
  `- 2:0:0:1 sde 8:64  active ghost running
```

We did a multipath reload but still the path is not coming up.

Output of multipath -d -v3:

```
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: dev_t = 8:0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: size = 143155200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: product = ROOT VOLUME
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: rev = V1.0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: h:b:t:l = 0:0:0:0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: serial = 81E7BEB0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: path checker = directio (config file default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | directio: starting new request
Aug 04 01:02:22 | directio: io finished 4096/0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: state = 3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (config file default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: uid = SIBM_ROOT_VOLUME_81E7BEB0 (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: prio = const (config file default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: const prio = 1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: dev_t = 8:16
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: size = 209715200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: h:b:t:l = 1:0:0:0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: serial = SF64601751
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | loading /lib64/multipath/libcheckrdac.so checker
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: state = 3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe780000107d53df601c (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | loading /lib64/multipath/libpriordac.so prioritizer
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdb: rdac prio = 6
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: dev_t = 8:32
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: size = 209715200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: h:b:t:l = 2:0:0:0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: serial = SF64601404
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: state = 5
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe780000107d53df601c (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdc: rdac prio = 1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-0: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-1: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sr0: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | md0: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-2: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-3: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: dev_t = 8:48
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: size = 209715200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: h:b:t:l = 1:0:0:1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: serial = SF64601751
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: state = 3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe78000010c9545afa11 (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdd: rdac prio = 6
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-4: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: dev_t = 8:64
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: size = 209715200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: h:b:t:l = 2:0:0:1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: serial = SF64601404
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: state = 5
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe78000010c9545afa11 (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sde: rdac prio = 1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-5: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: dev_t = 8:80
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: size = 209715200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: h:b:t:l = 1:0:0:2
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: serial = SF64601751
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: state = 5
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe0000000f8b5472ee8f (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdf: rdac prio = 1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-6: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: dev_t = 8:96
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: size = 209715200
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: h:b:t:l = 2:0:0:2
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: serial = SF64601404
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: state = 3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe0000000f8b5472ee8f (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdg: rdac prio = 6
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-7: device node name blacklisted
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: mask = 0x1f
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: dev_t = 8:112
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: size = 104857600
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: subsystem = scsi
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: vendor = IBM
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: product = 1726-4xx  FAStT
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: rev = 0617
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: h:b:t:l = 1:0:0:3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: tgt_node_name = 0x200400a0b82fbe7
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: serial = SF64601751
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: path checker = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: checker timeout = 60000 ms (sysfs setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: state = 3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: getuid = /lib/udev/scsi_id -g -u -s /block/%n (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: uid = 3600a0b80002fbe78000010df55bad187 (callout)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: prio = rdac (controller setting)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sdh: rdac prio = 6
Aug 04 01:02:22 | dm-8: device node name blacklisted
===== paths list =====
uuid                              hcil    dev dev_t pri dm_st chk_st vend/prod
SIBM_ROOT_VOLUME_81E7BEB0         0:0:0:0 sda 8:0   1   undef ready  IBM,ROOT
3600a0b80002fbe780000107d53df601c 1:0:0:0 sdb 8:16  6   undef ready  IBM,1726-
3600a0b80002fbe780000107d53df601c 2:0:0:0 sdc 8:32  1   undef ghost  IBM,1726-
3600a0b80002fbe78000010c9545afa11 1:0:0:1 sdd 8:48  6   undef ready  IBM,1726-
3600a0b80002fbe78000010c9545afa11 2:0:0:1 sde 8:64  1   undef ghost  IBM,1726-
3600a0b80002fbe0000000f8b5472ee8f 1:0:0:2 sdf 8:80  1   undef ghost  IBM,1726-
3600a0b80002fbe0000000f8b5472ee8f 2:0:0:2 sdg 8:96  6   undef ready  IBM,1726-
3600a0b80002fbe78000010df55bad187 1:0:0:3 sdh 8:112 6   undef ready  IBM,1726-
Aug 04 01:02:22 | params = 1 queue_if_no_path 1 rdac 1 1 round-robin 0 1 1 8:112 1000
Aug 04 01:02:22 | status = 2 0 0 0 1 1 E 0 1 0 8:112 A 0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | params = 1 queue_if_no_path 1 rdac 2 1 round-robin 0 1 1 8:16 1000 round-robin 0 1 1 8:32 1000
Aug 04 01:02:22 | status = 2 0 0 0 2 1 E 0 1 0 8:16 A 0 E 0 1 0 8:32 A 0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | params = 1 queue_if_no_path 1 rdac 2 1 round-robin 0 1 1 8:96 1000 round-robin 0 1 1 8:80 1000
Aug 04 01:02:22 | status = 2 0 1 0 2 1 A 0 1 0 8:96 A 0 E 0 1 0 8:80 A 0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | params = 1 queue_if_no_path 1 rdac 2 1 round-robin 0 1 1 8:48 1000 round-robin 0 1 1 8:64 1000
Aug 04 01:02:22 | status = 2 0 1 0 2 1 A 0 1 0 8:48 A 0 E 0 1 0 8:64 A 0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | Found matching wwid [SIBM_ROOT_VOLUME_81E7BEB0] in bindings file. Setting alias to mpath0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: ownership set to mpath0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: not found in pathvec
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: mask = 0xc
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: get_state
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: state = running
Aug 04 01:02:22 | directio: starting new request
Aug 04 01:02:22 | directio: io finished 4096/0
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: state = 3
Aug 04 01:02:22 | sda: const prio = 1
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: pgfailover = -1 (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: pgpolicy = failover (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: selector = round-robin 0 (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: features = 0 (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: hwhandler = 0 (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: rr_weight = 1 (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: minio = 1000 (config file default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: no_path_retry = NONE (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | pg_timeout = NONE (internal default)
Aug 04 01:02:22 | mpath0: set ACT_CREATE (map does not exist)
create: mpath0 (SIBM_ROOT_VOLUME_81E7BEB0) undef IBM,ROOT VOLUME
size=68G features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=undef
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=1 status=undef
  `- 0:0:0:0 sda 8:0   undef ready running
```

Comment: With your "echo" command, you rescanned ONLY one SCSI host (host0), while your multipath output clearly shows that aggregated LUNs are distributed along two SCSI hosts (eg: sdg 2:0:0:2; sdf 1:0:0:2 - see http://tldp.org/HOWTO/SCSI-2.4-HOWTO/scsiaddr.html ). Please ensure to rescan ALL the SCSI hosts on your system.